# Element-wise comparison with certain precision

Tags: raku, rakudo

I am looking for testing output of my function (which returns **array**) with the expected **output array**.

Example:

```raku
use Test;
sub myoutput($n) {
    (1..$n)>>.sqrt
}

is myoutput(3), (1, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772);
```

This looks fine but I want to set *precision* to `1e-12`.

What I came out with is this:

```raku
sub element_wise_testing_with_precision(@functionoutput, @expectedoutput, $precision) {
    die "Provide equal elements!" if +@functionoutput != +@expectedoutput;
    loop (my $i = 0; $i < +@functionoutput; $i++)  {
        is-approx @functionoutput[$i], @expectedoutput[$i], $precision;
    }
}


my @expected = (1, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772);
element_wise_testing_with_precision(myoutput(3), @expected, 1e-12)
```

Works (!) but not sure if it is the right way. Are there approaches to do this thing using [Z operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_Z) or [Hyper operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) as they appear to do element-wise operation?

Comment: Absolute precision or relative precision?

Comment: Its `:$abs-tol`, absolute precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your instincts about hyper and zip/the Z operator are exactly correct: it's possible to do what you want with either of them.  The missing piece of the puzzle is [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) (which Raku often calls [priming](https://design.raku.org/S06.html#Priming)).  Raku offers two ways to prime – that is, partially apply – a function: the [`.assuming`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/assuming) method (to prime a subroutine) and [Whatever-priming](https://docs.raku.org/type/Whatever) (to prime an operator or method).

Since `&is-approx` is a subroutine, `&assuming` is the priming method we're after.  To specify precision as the third argument, we'd write `&is-approx.assuming(*, *, $precision)`.  Or, since `&is-approx` allows specifying precision with a named argument, we can simplify that to `&is-approx.assuming: :abs-tol($precision)`.

Once we've done that, we can apply our new function element wise using the [hyper](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) or Z metaoperators.  Note that, because metaoperators expects an infix operator, we'll need to use the [infix form](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Infix_form) of our function by wrapping our function in square brackets.

Here's your code with those minimal changes:

```raku
sub element_wise_testing_with_precision(@functionoutput, @expectedoutput, $precision) {
    die "Provide equal elements!" if +@functionoutput != +@expectedoutput;

    my &close-enough = &is-approx.assuming(*,*, $precision);
    @functionoutput «[&close-enough]» @expectedoutput

  # or this also works:
  # @functionoutput Z[&close-enough] @expectedoutput
}
```

Here's a version with some tangential changes to make it a bit more idiomatic:

```raku
sub element-wise-is-approx(@got, @expected, $abs-tol) {
    PRE { +@got == +@expected }

    my &close-enough = &is-approx.assuming: :$abs-tol;
    @got «[&close-enough]» @expected
}

element-wise-is-approx(myoutput(3), @expected, 1e-12);
```

Indeed, we could even do this inline, as shown below.  Here, we switch to the non-DWIM version of hyper (`» «`), to enforce equal-sized arguments.

```raku
myoutput(3) »[&(&is-approx.assuming(*,*,1e-12))]« @expected
```

(Note the extra `&(  )` in in the infix operator is required to clarify our intent to the Raku compiler.)

Comment: As always, great explanation. Many new things for me. Thank you @codesections Few comments: in second function `@got «[&is-approx]» @expected` may be typo, need to be `&close-enough` in the middle I guess. In your third code, I get this warning `Potential difficulties:
    Useless use of »[&(&is-approx.assuming(*,*,1e-12))]« in sink context`. Any idea to get rid of it?

Comment: @SumanKhanal, thanks for pointing out the (now-fixed) typo and out the "sink context" warning.  I believe the latter is a Rakudo bug; I'll file an issue if there isn't one already.  Until that's fixed, you can silence the warning by assigning the result to an unused variable `my $ = myoutput(3) »[&(&is-approx.assuming(*,*,1e-12))]« @expected` or by running it in a `subtest`.  Or silence all warnings with a `quietly` block (https://docs.raku.org/syntax/quietly%20%28statement%20prefix%29), but that seems like overkill here.

Comment: There was already a bug: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4424  I added some details and linked to this SO question.

Comment: This seems like an extraordinarily-advanced answer, especially for new Raku users. Any chance the OP might find a `$*TOLERANCE` of `1e-15` acceptable? See second answer to this question (add a `.grep` if so desired).

Comment: Not clear to me whether the OP wants absolute tolerance or relative tolerance. Can @SumanKhanal clarify?

Comment: @jubilatious1 Its :$abs-tol, absolute precision.

Comment: @raiph IIRC (from reading past discussions; I wasn't there), the thought was to avoid jargon that we don't use that often (lord knows we've got enough of our _own_ jargon!).  But in other contexts – including S06 – we use "priming" instead of "partial application".  So if we moved away from "whatever-currying", I'd probably go with "priming"

Comment: @raiph ah, now I'm with you.  I edited the answer so that it now describes `&assuming` as a way to prime/partially-apply instead of currying.  I left the reference to "whatever currying", though, since that term is used in the docs (and, imo, is a less-clearly-incorrect usage, though I'm not sure it's _correct_)

Comment: @codesections   I just poked around and see I maligned Larry, whose role relative to use of the word "curry" was in fact to try and *stop* Rakoons using it, because, he said, Rakoons and non-Rakoons alike *mis*use it. Instead he said what Raku was doing with both `.assuming` *and* `Whatever`s -> `WhateverCode` was "partial application aka priming". So now I'm thinking we should be considering eradicating all use of "curry", "curried" etc in the doc‡, and rename "Whatever currying" to "Whatever priming". [ ‡ Correct use would be OK, but I found none. ]

Comment: @raiph here you go: https://github.com/Raku/doc/pull/4397

Answer (score 2):

***Try Raku's built-in `=~=` "tolerance" operator, with the hyper/Z calls you envision.***

The `=~=` "tolerance" operator reads the `$*TOLERANCE` dynamic variable, which defaults to `1e-15`, see link at bottom.

```perl
~$ seq 1 16 |  \
   awk '{print sqrt($0)}' |  \
   raku -e  'my @awk = lines;  
             my @raku = (1..16).map: *.sqrt;  \
             .say for [Z=~=] @awk,@raku;'
True
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
```

Breaking out the inputs, first **awk**:

```
~$ seq 1 16 | awk '{print sqrt($0)}'
1
1.41421
1.73205
2
2.23607
2.44949
2.64575
2.82843
3
3.16228
3.31662
3.4641
3.60555
3.74166
3.87298
4
```

And **Raku**'s default precision:

```
~$ raku -e '.sqrt.put for (1..16);'
1
1.4142135623730951
1.7320508075688772
2
2.23606797749979
2.449489742783178
2.6457513110645907
2.8284271247461903
3
3.1622776601683795
3.3166247903554
3.4641016151377544
3.605551275463989
3.7416573867739413
3.872983346207417
4
```

I recognize the OP requested a tolerance of `1e-12` but maybe the higher tolerance of `1e-15` might prove acceptable? Without seeing the OP's desired output, I can only guess that the `[Z=~=]` one-liner might be acceptable, with/without an additional `.grep` call.

[ Re: Tolerance--I don't see a way to set the `$*TOLERANCE` dynamic variable such that the `=~=` infix operator reads the new value. Setting `$*TOLERANCE = 1e-12` throws an error *Cannot modify an immutable Num (1e-15)* ].

[ Raku also has a related function, `is-approx` ].

[https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3D~%3D](https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3D%7E%3D)
https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-approx
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742940/227738

Comment: `my $*TOLERANCE = ...` would make a new lexical dynamic variable for =~= to see without affecting the global one living in the PROCESS, which is bound to 1e-15 so unalterable as you said, which is good I guess not to globally change tolerance everywhere. Also more importantly, this checks relative difference not absolute which the question asker achieves via the abs-tol parameter of is-approx.